# Can ASP.Net Caching be used inside an MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

If so how do I get a hold of the Cache object?

I tried declaring a static Cache object in my controller (hoping it will not be disposed too frequently) like so:

private static readonly System.Web.Caching.Cache cache = new System.Web.Caching.Cache();

As soon as I call cache["MyObject"] I get a nullReference at System.Web.Caching.Cache.Get(String key)
(did the old ASP.Net Page class catch that? yuck!)

I need caching with a file dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create a brand new Cache object, you need to retrive it from HttpContext like this: `HttpContext.Cache`