# Asp.net cache not working on IIS. Is there any setting on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, caching

I create a basic cache sample like below. My code is running perfectly when I publish to my local IIS. But, when I publish my real server not working. There isn't any error. But cache is always empty. **What can be the reason of this? Is there any setting in IIS or another windows config?**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Caching;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ToplumMerkezleriCommonApi.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        protected ObjectCache Cache => MemoryCache.Default;
        protected CacheItemPolicy policy = null;

        public object Get(string id)
        {
            if (Cache.Get("testcache") == null)
            {
                GetAllCacheItems();
            }
            return Cache[id] as Object;
        }

        private void GetAllCacheItems()
        {
            using (CommunityCenterEntities context = new CommunityCenterEntities())
            {
                policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
                policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(24);

                Cache.Set("testcache", DateTime.Now.ToString(), policy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306126/can-asp-net-caching-be-used-inside-an-mvc-controller

Comment: Thanks for your reply @LexLi. I now tried with HttpContext.Cache. But, result not changed. It's not working

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60584547/how-to-configure-cache-on-iis-10) may help with your problem. Please check the points(`<clientcache>` section, enable web browser caching, use FRT check how the cache generated) which mentioned in the answer of the post.

Comment: Thanks for yor reply @HuryShen . I tried settings on the post. But not worked

Comment: Since all of the suggestions/solutions can't help with your problem, I think you can create a support about it on [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/) to ask microsoft engineer for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The problem is antivirus. Our antivirus is deleting static variables and cache values. So, when I close antivirus, cache worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please check, go to IIS manager->site node->output  caching->edit feature settings->uncheck enable cache
And
For Static files, you enable IIS manager->site node->HTTP Response header->Set common headers->expire web content->immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I now tried this settings. But, result not changed. It's not working